# How to check the classloader class hierarchy (precendence) in jboss deployment

Tags: java, jboss, classloader

I am working on a project and we are having issues related to a dependency, more than one projects are using the same class but in different versions (indirect dependencies). We now need to know the sequence in which class loader is loading the classes on the deployment server so that we can figure our which version of that dependency is correct.

Our project is deployed using wars on jboss.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/) to check loaded classes. [Use Tattletale to find application dependencies](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-UseTattletaletofindapplicationdependencies)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. As far as I can read it only gives details of application classloader but I am interested in seeing classes loaded by jboss and java as well. Do you have any idea how can I achieve that? I have this installed on the server https://github.com/lbovet/jminix but it doesn't provide what is needed (or at least I couldn't find it).